# error while compiling boost in android

Tags: android, c++, boost

I am trying to install boost 1.5 into android according to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-ndk/cVWzSa2kfuw).

When I compile, I get an error.  Here is a fragment of the compilation error:

```
gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/thread/build/gcc-android4.4.3/release/link-static/runtime-link-    static/threading-multi/pthread/thread.o
<command-line>: warning: "BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION" redefined
<command-line>: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from ./boost/thread/thread.hpp:17,
             from libs/thread/src/pthread/thread.cpp:11:
./boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp: In member function 'void    boost::thread_attributes::set_stack_size(size_t)':
./boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:42: error: 'PAGE_SIZE' was not declared in this scope

"../../toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++"  -ftemplate-depth-128 -O3 -finline-functions -Wno-inline -Wall -pedantic --sysroot=../../platforms/android-9/arch-arm -mthumb -Os -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -lstdc++ -I../../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include -I../../sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/libs/armeabi/include -D__GLIBC__ -DBOOST_NO_INTRINSIC_WCHAR_T -DBOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION=2 -pthread -Wextra -Wno-long-long -pedantic -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 -DBOOST_CHRONO_STATIC_LINK=1 -DBOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION=3 -DBOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED -DBOOST_SYSTEM_STATIC_LINK=1 -DBOOST_THREAD_BUILD_LIB=1 -DBOOST_THREAD_POSIX -DNDEBUG  -I"." -c -o "bin.v2/libs/thread/build/gcc-android4.4.3/release/link-static/runtime-link-static/threading-multi/pthread/thread.o" "libs/thread/src/pthread/thread.cpp"

...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2/libs/thread/build/gcc-android4.4.3/release/link-static/runtime-link-static/threading-multi/pthread/thread.o...
```

I found this error which I didn't understand ...

`./boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp:42: error: 'PAGE_SIZE' was not declared in this scope`. It says `PAGE_SIZE` was not declared, but I have no idea what that means.  And when I tried to look at that particular location in the code I did not find `PAGE_SIZE`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compilation errors like this are typically resolved by looking first at the preprocessed output.  Try replacing `-c` with `-E` and changing the `foo.o` to `foo.pp` (or something else) and review the `foo.pp` file for errors (search for `set_stack_size`).

This is the relevant code:

```
        void set_stack_size(std::size_t size) BOOST_NOEXCEPT {
          if (size==0) return;
          std::size_t page_size = getpagesize();
#ifdef PTHREAD_STACK_MIN
          if (size<PTHREAD_STACK_MIN) size=PTHREAD_STACK_MIN;
#endif
          size = ((size+page_size-1)/page_size)*page_size;
```

`getpagesize()` expands to something which references `PAGE_SIZE`.  I'm pretty sure `sysconf` is the Right Way (tm) to get the page size these days, but the boost maintainers might've had a good reason for using `getpagesize()`.  Regardless, you can dodge this specific error with a `-DPAGE_SIZE=2048` compiler argument, or whatever your target's page size is.   Either that, or patch the source to use `sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)` instead.

Comment: IT WORKS NOW -  the problem was in line :::  if (size<PTHREAD_STACK_MIN) size=PTHREAD_STACK_MIN; ::: no value was passed to the parameter size, so we need to feed manually ... the user-config.jam file should add <compileflags>-DPAGE_SIZE=2048 . my question now is, will adding 2048 this way be a good solution?? and thank you for your answer .

Comment: It's not an ideal solution, but it's adequate (but only if the page size really is 2048).

Comment: hey brian, really appreciate your answer .. i installed boost library into boost1.5/android/lib. The problem is i only get few static library of boost .. i actually need all the library of boost since i am trying to install a library into android that depends on boost + (other lib ). what do you think i should do ??

Comment: Ask a new question.  ;)  I think that by default, all of the libraries get built (and the header-only libraries are merely installed).  Do the ones you're not "getting" fail to build, or what?

Comment: check my link to the question ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477267/install-a-library-that-depends-on-third-party-libraries-boost-etc-into-android )  ... build for boost is sucessfull but only 10 static lib of boost get build :( and i want dynamic lib of boost

Comment: its my bad english that is not letting me explain my problem properly :(

Answer (score 7):

Had this issue with 1.50 boost, ndk-r8b.

Thanks to this thread I managed to get it fixed with following changes :

file boost/thread/thread.hpp

```
// Fix for missing macro
#define PAGE_SIZE sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)

#include <boost/thread/pthread/thread_data.hpp>
```

Note that I also needed to change this since the 1.50 boost:

file boost/libs/filesystem/src/operations.cpp

```
# ifdef BOOST_POSIX_API

    const fs::path dot_path(".");
    const fs::path dot_dot_path("..");
#   include <sys/types.h>
#   include <sys/stat.h>
#   if !defined(__APPLE__) && !defined(__OpenBSD__) && !defined(ANDROID)
#     include <sys/statvfs.h>
#     define BOOST_STATVFS statvfs
#     define BOOST_STATVFS_F_FRSIZE vfs.f_frsize
#   elif defined (ANDROID)
#     include <sys/vfs.h>
#     define BOOST_STATVFS statfs
#     define BOOST_STATVFS_F_FRSIZE static_cast<boost::uintmax_t>(vfs.f_bsize)
#   else
#     ifdef __OpenBSD__
#     include <sys/param.h>
#     endif
#     include <sys/mount.h>
#     define BOOST_STATVFS statfs
#     define BOOST_STATVFS_F_FRSIZE static_cast<boost::uintmax_t>(vfs.f_bsize)
#   endif
```

Comment: For the record, this seems to be fixed in NDK R8E