# Install a library that depends on third party libraries boost,etc  into android 

Tags: boost, android-ndk

I have my boost installed in android (inside /android-sdk/ndk/source/boost/android/lib)

I have a software(library) running in linux and it uses boost(1.47 and up) library.

I want to have that software run in android.

when i try to install the software into android i have to include boost include/library . so my queston is should i use boost include/library of android or should i use boost include/library that is installed for linux, but if i use boost library installed for android installation give error said some lib are not found (since boost android doesnt support all the lib of boost)

Comment: Have you successfully built all the software that you intend to install on Android, including dynamically linked libs (boost etc), with the NDK toolchain? If yes, your application should not have any problem loading the libs.

Comment: no i am still stuck in figuring out whether to do with cmake or ndk-build to build the software into android .. when i try to install boost in android only few static lib are created .. but i want all the lib of boost (both static and dynamic) to be ported into android .. is there a script for that ?? or do i have to do individually of each lib i want ?? ...